# Jquery UI Autocomplete custom data doesn't works as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete with custom data like JQUI docs [illustrate](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Here is my Javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
    type   : 'POST',
    url    : '/loadUserCompanyByAjax',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.error == null) {
            var dataArray = [];
            $.each(result.companies,function(index,element){
                dataArray.push({
                    name : element.name,
                    id : element._id
                });
            });

            $( '.companyNameFromCreateMoe:empty' ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: dataArray,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(this ).val( ui.item.name );
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    alert(ui.item.id);

                    return false;
                }
            })
                .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.name +"</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
        }
        else {
            alert('AN ERROR HAS OCCURED DURING GETTING COMPANIES : ' + result.error);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that when i begin to type a letter nothing is happening excepted if i type the letter "e"...

[image]
[image]

And when i type the following the autocomplete list disapears..

[image]

If i change my dataArray by the Array given in exemple it works.

Here the content of my dataArray :

```
[
    {
        "name":"SARL salut ça va",
        "id":"55bdd266b1257b401d405ead"
    },
    {
        "name":"EURL Marco plomberie",
        "id":"55bde8b3e633d33c1ecfbecc"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source list objects should have the keys "label" and "value".
Read the documentation for the source property: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

you should change your loop to create dataArray like this

```
$.each(result.companies, function (index, element) {
    dataArray.push({
        label: element.name,
        value: element._id
    });
});
```

Here is the detailed fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/sqfwhxmj/1/

Hope it helps.